# How to measure the distance of an object in-front of IOS Device while app is running in Background?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, iphone-x, face-id

How to measure the distance of an object in-front of an IOS Device (iPhone and iPad) while app is running in Background?

I have been researching about using the Proximity Sensor however it only goes as far as giving true or false value whether there is an object in-front of the phone, compared to android SDK where it accurately gives the distance of the object.

If am not mistaken, we can achieve this precisely using ARKit or just by using the camera alone, however Apple restricts the use of camera in the background.

The objective is to set the user in an optimal distance to the device while being used, even in background.

Not sure if the new TrueDepth camera of iphone X is any help.

Hoping for any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably train a model on the device gyro, to predict different holding patters. Not sure if this will work, but its worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I agree, this is worth a try. Been thinking of it as well, it would probably take more time to study, but yeah.

Comment: The proximity sensor is used so know if you're holding the phone on your face when in call, not very suited for what you want. Is knowing the distance the solution? Also why you need background use? I can't really think of a solution without more hints, it depends on what you want to achieve and the precision needed.